# Why am I not able to export the color of my 3D animated object from blender to Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, textures, blender

I have created a 3D model of a bird and even animation for that. But when I exported it into the .fbx file into Unity I am not able to see the color.

I saw various tutorials on youtube(described below) but it didn't help.

Firstly I selected the bird and the bird mesh. Then selected file->Export fbx. In fbx I did the following changes:

- checked the selected object check box
- Object types were Armature and Mesh
- Transform Z-forward
- under armature unchecked leaf bones
- Under Bake animations unchecked NLA strips and force Start/end key
  [image: method 1]

When I exported in the fbx file I was in the 3D viewer was able to see the object and the animation as well. But when I imported to Unity I couldnt see the color or texture of the object (bird)

Secondly I selected the bird and the bird mesh. Then selected file->External data->Pack all into .blend and then selected export fbx. In fbx I did the following changes:

- checked the selected object check box
- path mode was copy and that little icon next to that was also selected
- Object types were Armature and Mesh

But still I didnt work
[image: method 2]

Thirdly I tried saving my .blend file directly in my assets folder of Unity but the image was strongly lit and very bright. I understood that was because of the blender Camera and lighting. So I deleted those components as well in blender and saved my file using in the assets folder of my unity.Still the textures or color of the 3D animated object was not seen. I mean why is this happening and how to fix it?

<<<<<<------------EDIT 1--------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>>>
[image: Unity SS as seen]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried dragging the texture maps your bird has in the assets folder?

Comment: No, I mean I have no texture maps but I have Material.002 file which in the inspector panel is greyed out .I have updated my question with the screenshot of the Unity file as seen

Comment: So you saved it as a .blend file and dragged it into the Project tab of your Unity project?

Comment: Yeah I one of the methods I did that

Comment: Then I don't know I can't seem to see the problem, I am sorry.

Comment: It is Ok...thanks for the help....really appreciate that